# How to position slider image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place a slider from this link:

https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/full-slider/

I've kept my `header 650px; and carousel height: 100%`. While trying so I'm having other elements also, which are making the active slider to come below those elements.

Please review this link: http://www.jrnoordbgroups.com/

My active slider element is coming down. What CSS changes should I make?

Comment: it's for sale, not for sell.

Comment: We need to see the code you are using to be able to help

Comment: I have voted to close as off-topic because we need everything pertaining to the question to be in the question itself. I assume you will have fixed the link above, and if you have not done so then you will shortly, and at that point the question will not demonstrate the problem for future interested readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `carousel-inner` should have following style:

```
.carousel-inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Also so will have to play with z-indexes to make sure your content and header are above the carousel-inner or push it to be first element in the `header`

Answer (score 2):

Two ways to fix that:

Put the slider elements in the first section (where it belongs to). Some more adjustments needed...

```
<div class="container header-content">
        <div class="row">
               <!--here for example-->
               ...
```

Or set the slider position to absolute:

```
.carousel-inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```